# How can I convert an AudioClip to byte array in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to convert an AudioClip to byte array.

I'm actually only interested to load the asset (.ogg file for this matter)
as a byte[] if there is a shorter way.

Comment: Can you give more details?  e.g. How is the .ogg stored/retrieved.

Comment: I dragged the ogg file into the project tab, added a new game object (as an Audio source) and dragged the ogg file to the Audio clip text box

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if we could know for what purposes you want to do this.